# Sequelize: Sync from scratch

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

In my testing environment, I drop the database and then recreate it from scratch every time I test.

Using the `sequelize.sync({ force: true });` method is giving me trouble. Basically, all my models are setup with the the appropriate relationships in the `associate(models)` method but when creating the tables from scratch, it seems that Sequelize attempts to create the table and its relations all at once which throws errors since some of the tables referenced in the relations are not created at that point. I get the following error:

```
ERROR: relation "tableName" does not exist
```

Since `sequelize.sync()` is an async operation, tableName changes depending on which query was sent to the database server first. However, examining the database logs, all the queries that have non existent tables referenced do indeed throw an error.

This does not seem like normal behaviour to me. Where am I going wrong? Do I have to wrap the association process in a transaction?

Comment: If you are getting `ERROR: relation "tableName" does not exist` wouldn't that mean tableName is being passed in as a string? Don't you want `tableName` to be a variable ?

Comment: @realseanp In postgres you must use quotations otherwise the queries are not case sensitive. This is not the issue here. The problem is the table creation order.